# PHP Form - Check if mysql already contains email data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This register form was made by me, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

I want it to connect to a mysql database and store the information that was given by the form. I want it to hash the `$password` in md5 and store it in the "gebruikers" table. Please don't reply with *"Damn, you have no idea what you are doing"* or something like that. I am learning PHP by looking to examples and following tutorials. Please keep in mind that the mysql insert code is not filled in right, because I got stuck a few lines above.

So, my question is: I want to check if the mysql table already contains `$email`. If it IS already in the mysql table, I want to display an error message that I can place somewhere else in my PHP page. If the email adress given is unique, than the `$password` should hash into md5 and store into the mysql database, just like the other form entries.

How do I do that?

```
                        <?php
                            // Fetching all the form details
                            $email = $_POST["email"];
                            $password = $_POST["password"];
                            $voornaam = $_POST["voornaam"];
                            $tussenvoegsel = $_POST["tussenvoegsel"];
                            $achternaam = $_POST["achternaam"];
                            $dag = $_POST["dag"];
                            $maand = $_POST["maand"];
                            $jaar = $_POST["voornaam"];
                            $straat = $_POST["straat"];
                            $postcode = $_POST["postcode"];
                            $woonplaats = $_POST["woonplaats"];
                            $cniveau = $_POST["cniveau"];
                            $oniveau = $_POST["oniveau"];
                            $voornaam = $_POST["voornaam"];
                            $aboutme = $_POST["aboutme"];

                            //Here's where I don't know how to continue
                            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gebruikers` WHERE `email` = '$email'"); 
                            if($check === FALSE) {
                            //there is a user already registered 
                             echo("$email is al in gebruik. <a href='login.php'>Inloggen</a>?"); 
                            } else { 
                            //There isn't a username 
                            //mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`id` ,`username` ,`password`) VALUES (NULL , '{$_POST['email']}', MD5( '{$_POST['password']}' ))"); 
                            echo("You have been registered!"); 
                            }
```

P.S.: I'm not a native English speaker, so please ignore my grammar mistakes/typos.

Comment: Please be aware. Your code is vulnerable to SQl Injection. Please use either PDO or mysqli_*.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response Chris! So do I need to change mysql to mysqli to bypass the SQL injection?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you made a major mistake: There is a SQL-Injection security hole.
Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
Second, you should use mysqli instead of mysql, because mysql is deprecated.

Your error is that SQL does only return false if the query is invalid, not if there are no results. So the correct way of checking if there are results is to use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Okay, I think I've done that already a few hours ago, but it did display something like Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gebruikers` WHERE `email` = '$email' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false)
{
    ...
} else { 
    ....
}
```

You should also read up on preventing SQL injection.

Comment: Oh. Probably because you're not establishing a DB connection anywhere. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: No, I did. I just didn't post my details here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgot to set the `mysql_connect` statement.

But I strongly recommend you stick from now on, with the `mysqli_` functionality, since, as Aragon0 said, mysql is deprecated in PHP's newest versions.

Besides, mysqli statements are simpler than the mysql ones, for example you use one statement (`mysqli_connect`) to connect to your host and select your database at the same time, instead of using separated statements (both `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`).

Oh, and no additional service package is required to use it. :)

Comment: Plus, all the `mysql_` functions are named in the same way in `mysqli_`, the difference between both is how the parameters are inserted. 

Few are removed in it's parallel version. Look at them in the php api: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php